# How to remove lines that do NOT end with a particular sequence with regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to use regex to find all words in a dictionary file that end with a particular character sequence. I currently use the following regex

```
.*charsequence$
```

which nicely matches all entries in my dictionary that end with my charsequence.

But now I actually want to invert this regex to match all lines that do NOT end with my charsequence, so I can replace them with the empty string and end up with a nice list of dictionary entries ending with my charsequence. I tried negating the charsequence part by using the following regex:

```
.*[^(charsequence)]$
```

the resulting list does seem to contain all original entries ending with my charsequence, but it still also contains some entries that do not end with my charsequence.

Note: lots of similar questions on stackoverflow, but I was not able to find one that completely covered my particular case. Most of the similar questions seem either to focus on removing lines that do not START with a particular sequence, or focus on removing lines that do not end with a particular character (opposed to a sequence of characters).

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: If you're using grep, the -v flag will invert results, so if you have a regex that matches the lines you don't want, then you can invert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a negative lookahead to match all the lines except the one which ends with `charsequence`

```
^(?!.*charsequence$).*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xE6aD0/3)

Comment: it matches because the string `charsequence` is not at the end.

Comment: I think in this case, greedy `.*` will probably slightly faster, since it doesn't have to check against charsequence until the end of line. (It only checks against line terminators).

Comment: @nhahtdh no, debugger shows the above regex as a faster one. I think it's because of backtracking. `.*` would match upto the end at first and then backtracks to get a match.

Comment: Not too sure about the actual performance, though. But use the debugger and check 2 cases `.*` and `.*?`, the `.*` uses less steps to complete than `.*?` http://regex101.com/r/nG3tY4/1 with internal optimization enabled (the same result if we compare both when we disable the optimization). This only applies for PCRE.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:.(?!charsequence$))*$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/xT7yD8/15

Comment: Checking and matching of each character followed by not of `charsequence` would take more number of steps.